# compute $\iint_Y F.N\ dS $ with Gauss

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, line-integrals

The question is:
$$ \iint_Y F.N\ dS \quad Y=(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2=1+z^2,\ \  0\leq z\leq 1 \quad N=\text{pointing outward}
$$ $$ F=(y,x,1+x^2z)$$
Here is how I have tried to solve it: I tried to solve it with Gauss theorem like this, $\gamma=\text{upper lid}$, $\sigma=\text{lower lid} $
$$ \iint_{Y+\sigma+\gamma}F.N\ dS=\iiint_K \text{div}f\  dA \iff \iint_Y F.N\ dS=\iiint_k-\iint_\sigma-\iint_\gamma$$
$$ \iint_\sigma=-\pi, \iint_\gamma=2+\pi$$
But I have trouble to integrate this triple integral
$$ \iiint_kx^2 dxdydz$$
I don't know if I have been  calculating right so far, and how should I proceed? Any suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: The flux through upper lid does not seem correct.

Comment: @MathLover I also suspected this :), this question is very difficult i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface is $(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 = 1 + z^2$

$\vec F = (y,x,1+x^2z)$

To apply divergence theorem, we close the surface with discs at $z = 0$ and at $z = 1$.

a) Flux through disc at $z = 1$,

Plugging in $z = 1$ in the equation of hyperboloid, we get the equation of the disc as

$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = 2$

In polar coordinates, $x = 1 + \rho \cos\theta, y = 1+\rho \sin\theta, z = 1 \ (0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi)$

Outward normal vector is $(0, 0, 1)$.

So the integral to find flux becomes

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt2} [1+(1+ \rho \cos\theta)^2] \  \rho \ d\rho \ d\theta = 5 \pi$

b) Flux through the disc at $z = 0$ is simply the area of the disc with negative sign as $\vec F \cdot (0,0,-1) = -1$. So it is $-\pi$ as you correctly calculated.

c) Now to find flux through the closed surface, apply divergence theorem.

$\nabla \cdot \vec F = x^2$ as you mentioned.

Now the region for triple integral is a hyperboloid which is difficult to calculate without a Jacobian. So as the other answer suggests,

use change of variable $x = u + w, y = v + w, z = w$. Its Jacobian is $1$.

So the transformed region is $u^2 + v^2 - w^2 = 1$. In cylindrical coordinates,

$u = \rho \cos \theta, v = \rho \sin \theta, w$

$0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt{1+w^2}, 0 \leq w \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $

Integrand $x^2 = (u+w)^2 = (\rho \cos \theta + w)^2$

So integral to find flux,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_0^{\sqrt{1+w^2}} (\rho \cos \theta + w)^2 \ \rho \ d\rho \ dw \ d\theta = \pi$.

d) So flux through hyperboloid surface $ = \pi - 5 \pi - (-\pi) = - 3 \pi$

Comment: One interesting fact that I should call out - this is not a hyperboloid which is tilted, rather it is an oblique hyperboloid. So as long as the height is the same (in this case $z$), its volume will remain the same as a hyperboloid which had cross-sections with same radius along $z-$ axis and that is why it easily transforms to $u^2+v^2-w^2 = 1$ with Jacobian $1$. This is true for other solids like cylinder, cone etc. Look up oblique cylinder and cone for example, if you have not already dealt with them in the past.

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover

Answer (score 1):

You can use transformation $f(x,y,z)=(x+z,y+z,z)$. The jacobian of this transform is 1. You get:$$
\iiint_{k'}(x+z)^2dxdydz
$$
where $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.

Using cylindric coordinates, you can transform it to:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{1+z^2}}(\rho\cos\phi+z)^2\rho d\rho d\phi dz
$$
Does this help you?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks